# JedisDataException: ERR WATCH inside MULTI is not allowed

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, redis, jedis

I use jedis for the use of Redis database. The software is based on AWS services like Redis, SQS, SMS and Kubernetes with PODs etc. 
Actually everything works fine but once I had the following exception: "JedisDataException: ERR WATCH inside MULTI is not allowed", which happened at the place as is visible in the code. I couldn't make any more requests to Redis (no matter what kind of key I wanted to use). After restarting the POD everything works perfectly. 
I can't reproduce the error anymore.

Do you have any idea what's the problem? 
I quess it has something to do with aws-sqs or scaling of PODs and concurrency.

the sequence of events is: event --> aws:sns --> aws:sqs --> k8s:POD (java code) --> add value to aws:redis

Thank you.

```
public boolean add(key, value) {
   jedis.watch(key);

   Transaction tx = jedis.multi();

   tx.hsetnx(key, value, json);

   if (tx.exec().size() == 0) {

      LOGGER.warn("nothing executed...");
   } else {
      LOGGER.debug("add bike executed...");
   }

   jedis.resetState();
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this line `tx.hsetnx(key, value, json);` throws an exception which makes this transaction is opened forever, subsequent requests(new call to the method) start executing the steps like a watch and as the transaction is opened already and running watch on the same connection might throw the error?.

When you do pod recycling/restarting, means the pod got destroyed which is holding the connection got closed and eventually, the transaction got closed.
Hence, you don't seem to get this error but this problem can reoccur if there is an exception occurs before you run the EXEC command.